# Servname not supported for ai_socktype

Tags: sockets, centos, ip, port, perforce

I'm running a Centos virtual machine using Vagrant. The machine seems to run properly, but when I try to sync Perforce I can see the following error:

```
[vagrant@vagrant-c5-x86_64 ~]$ /perforce/p4 sync -f ...  
Perforce client error:  
Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.  
failed.TCP connect to perforce.xxx.com:1666  
Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

I have read this http://www.ducea.com/2006/09/11/error-servname-not-supported-for-ai_socktype/ and tried to set the ports in `/etc/services`, but it didn't work. I am not even sure if the problem is Perforce or OS related.

Any hints?

Comment: Have you set P4PORT correctly?

Comment: Yes, that was my first guess. It was correctly set from the beginning. Also, I changed P4CHARSET to 'utf8' and 'none'. No results so far...

Comment: Does "telnet perforce.xxx.com 1666" work? (i.e. establish a connection)

Comment: It does work. The machines can see each other.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600239/perl-unit-test-for-connection-to-perforce-connect-to-server-failed-check-p4 for a similar question, with an answer, although in that case the answer involved a syntax error in a Perl script. Still, maybe it gives a clue to the answer to this question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had this problem with a Tornado/Python app. Apparently, [this can be caused](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/352#issuecomment-18704043) by the port being interpreted as a string instead of an integer. So in my case, I needed to change my startup script to force it to be interpreted as an integer.

```
application = tornado.web.Application(...)
application.listen(int(port))
```

Comment: Completely different library (Kafka-Python) but this resolved my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to enter your client ? before trying to sync the files, try to create a perforce client:

```
p4 client
```

Maybe it's not the `host:port` that is the issue, but other flags in the connection string that interrupt.

I personally received the exact same error, but it was a Perforce issue.

The reason is, Perforce has its own priority when it's looking for its `P4USER`/`P4PORT`/... configuration.

1. ENV variables ( run `export` )
2. if a `P4CONFIG` variable was specified somewhere it can search in a file ( like `.perforce` in the current/upper directory )

Problem was, even though it first search for an ENV variable - the `P4CONFIG` file might override it.

So my `$P4PORT` ENV variable had a connection string X, but the `.perforce` file had a connection string Y.

Removing the `P4PORT` from my local `.perforce` file - solved this issue.
in example:

```
$~] echo $P4PORT; 
rsh:ssh -2 -q -a -x -l p4ssh perforce.mydomain.com

$~] cat .perforce
# P4PORT="rsh:ssh -q -a -x -l perforce.mydomain.com /bin/true"
P4USER="my_user"
```

Also remember that Perforce will search for the `$P4CONFIG` file ( if configured one ) in the entire directory hierarchy upwards, so even if you don't have the file in the current directory - it might be found in an upper directory, and there - you might have a `$P4PORT` configuration that you didn't expect..

Answer (score 1):

Put trailing slash, e.g.:

```
http://perforce.xxx.com:1666/
```

Instead of:

```
http://perforce.xxx.com:1666
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got like this error in golang language, i changed my port type from string to int and works fine