# Perl Unit Test for Connection to Perforce -- Connect to Server Failed; check $P4PORT

Tags: perl, unit-testing, perforce

I am writing a P4Perl script to make connection to a Perforce server and to automate execution of Perforce commands. Along with the development of the subroutines to access Perforce, I am also developing unit tests to verify the them. I am new to both Perl and unit testing.

This is my subroutine to establish a connection to Perforce. Filename is `p4_connect.pl`

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use P4;

my $clientname = "johndoe"
my $p4port = "icmanage:1667"

main();

sub main {
    my $status;
    $status = connect_perforce($clientname, $p4port);
};

sub connect_perforce {

    my ($clientname, $p4port) = @_;
    my $status;
    my $p4 = new P4;

    $p4->SetClient( $clientname );
    $p4->SetPort( $p4port );
    $status = $p4->Connect() or die( "Failed to connect to Perforce Server" );

    return $status;
}
```

The Perl script executes fine when I run `"perl p4_connect.pl"`, no errors are thrown.

However, when I moved the `connect_perforce` subroutine to a package module `(Perforce.pm)` and wrote a unit test `(perforce.t)` for it, I encountered these errors:

```
username@hostname% perl -Ilib t/perforce.t
ok 1 - use Perforce;
ok 2 - Perforce->can('connect_perforce')
Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
TCP connect to johndoe failed.
Servname not supported for ai_socktype
Failed to connect to Perforce Server at lib/Perforce.pm line 16.
```

This is how the unit test `(perforce.t)` looks like:

```
use Perforce;

use warnings;
use strict;
use Test::More qw(no_plan);

use P4;

BEGIN { use_ok('Perforce'); } #package can be loaded

can_ok('Perforce', 'connect_perforce'); #subroutine connect_perforce exists

my $p4port = "icmanage:1667";
my $p4 = Perforce->connect_perforce(qw(johndoe $p4port)); #accessing the connect_perforce() subroutine
```

And this is how the my package `(Perforce.pm)` looks like:

```
package Perforce;

use warnings;
use strict;

use P4;

   sub connect_perforce {

   my ($clientname, $p4port) = @_;
   my $status;
   my $p4 = new P4;

   $p4->SetClient( $clientname );
   $p4->SetPort( $p4port );
   $status = $p4->Connect() or die( "Failed to connect to Perforce Server" );

   return $status;
}
```

Where did I go wrong regarding my unit test? Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but one of your programs sets `$p4port` to `icmanage.com:1667`, while the other one sets it to `icmanage:1667`. The message "Servname not supported for ai_socktype" makes your question sound very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079017/servname-not-supported-for-ai-socktype, by the way. The message makes me think that some networking software library is trying to find a 'icmanage' service in the network configuration files?

Comment: I'm very sorry, it's a typo. It has been duly corrected

Comment: The `new P4` should be `P4->new` with the arrow. That's the only place in that code where you should have that arrow because the indirect object notation is ambiguous. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing object orientated Perl and functional Perl, and you have fallen victim to it.

When you call a function as a method with the arrow operator `->`, Perl passes the thing on the left hand side as the first argument to the function<sup>1</sup>. In case of a package name, that's just the package name.

```
package Foo;
sub frobnicate{ print "@_" }

package main;
Foo->frobnicate(1, 2, 3);
```

The output of this will be

```
Foo 1 2 3
```

So in your case, `connect_perforce` will get this assignment:

```
my ($clientname, $p4port) = ('Perforce', 'johndoe', 'icmanage:1667' );
```

So the variables will have these values:

```
$clientname: 'Perforce'
$p4port:     'johndoe'
```

And your `'icmanage:1667'` string gets lost.

When you don't have objects, don't use the arrow. The correct way to call this function (it's not a method!) is to use the fully qualified name including the package.

```
my $p4 = Perforce::connect_perforce('johndoe', $p4port);
```

I've removed this rather weird `qw()`. It would give you a literal `$p4port` instead of the value, so that was another bug which you would have encountered next.

Since we have established that you don't have a class, but rather a module, you also don't want to use `can_ok`. That's not the right kind of test for your use case. Instead, simply call the function like I showed above, and then do useful tests with the returned value. If the function isn't there, the test program will fail, and you'll notice.

```
BEGIN { use_ok('Perforce'); }

my $p4 = Perforce::connect_perforce('johndoe', 'icmanage:1667');

isa_ok($p4, 'P4'); # I guess..
```

For more information on object orientation and on modules, take a look at [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) and [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html), [perlnewmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnewmod.html) and [Exporter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter). Perlmaven has [some good articles](https://perlmaven.com/packages-modules-and-namespace-in-perl) too.

---

<sup>1) It does more, but that's not relevant here</sup>